# Build a selector

Tags: jquery-selectors

i try to build my own selector but I get errors.

firebug tell me:

missing ) after argument list

```
$("#for_" + $(this)attr('id') + "").click(function() {

    alert($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

could somebody help me plaese?

Comment: `$(this)attr('id')` is a syntax error. You probably want `$(this).attr('id')` (or simply `this.id`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#for_" + $(this)attr('id') + "").click(function() {
                   ^---
```

You're missing a `.`. at the indicated spot. Should be

```
$("#for_" + $(this).attr('id') + "").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#for_" + $(this).attr('id')).click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Didnt you forget "." before attr?